# XML equivalent of Android's loadAnimation

Tags: android, animation

Is there an XML equivalent of Android's `loadAnimation` function? I want to specify the animation to apply to a view in my layout XML.

I have an animation defined in an animation resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="359"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
```

How can I do the below in my layout XML?

```
    ImageButton main_button = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_rotate);
    main_button.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this from XML :)